# How to strip a 3D numpy array saved in a .txt file when trying to reopen it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I saved a bunch of 3D arrays into .txt files and would like to reopen them, however, I am having a ard time stripping them of the extra stuff and turning it back into a nparray. It seems to not be in the format to use any of the easier np.loadtxt from numpy. Here is what I get when I try to read the file...

```
['[[ 4.5177e+01  1.5709e+01 -2.3376e+01]\n',' [ 3.9789e+01  1.2330e+01 -2.4630e+00]\n', ' [ 3.9578e+01  1.6107e+01 -3.1490e+00]\n', ' [ 3.9285e+01  1.6824e+01  6.2000e-01]\n', ' [ 4.2083e+01  1.4330e+01  1.4770e+00]\n', ' [ 4.4570e+01  1.5651e+01 -1.1370e+00]\n', ' [ 4.3732e+01  1.9300e+01 -2.8900e-01]]']
```

I would just like the output as It was saved into the text file, a np array as such:

```
[[ 45.564  15.567 -23.417]
 [ 42.768  14.182 -21.219]
 [ 43.864  13.353 -17.643]
 [ 41.808   8.895  -9.964]
 [ 31.923  11.816  -8.006]
 [ 31.045   8.709  -5.931]]
```

Comment: You save a `str` display of an array, which is not designed for reading.  `loadtxt` loads clean `csv` files - ones without the brackets, just numbers in neat rows and columns.  To handle what you got, you'll need to strip out the []. and parse each line - split and convert.  Or make it more list like.  There's isn't a easy to use, out of the box, solution for this.

Comment: Yah, this is what I figured. I think in my case itll just be smarter to save it in a better way as JustLearning describes

Comment: "I saved a bunch of 3D arrays into .txt files and would like to reopen them," no, *that is not what you should do!*. Don't just *dump the string represenation of an object to a text file and call it serialization*. Use an *actual serialization format*. Why does this have to be `.txt`? Why no just use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load`? This would provide a portable binary format, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the format in which you store the array. Looks like you're actually saving a "view" of an array (a string) instead of the numerical data itself. Try this instead:

```
mport numpy as np                                                                                      
                                                                                                        
a = [[ 45.564,  15.567, -23.417],                                                                       
     [ 42.768,  14.182, -21.219],                                                                       
     [ 43.864,  13.353, -17.643],                                                                       
     [ 41.808,   8.895,  -9.964],                                                                       
     [ 31.923,  11.816,  -8.006],                                                                       
     [ 31.045,   8.709,  -5.931]]                                                                       
                                                                                                        
np.savetxt("a.txt", a)                                                                                  
                                                                                                        
loaded_a = np.loadtxt("a.txt")                                                                                 
                                                                                                        
print(loaded_a[0])
```

Notice the commas throughout the array.

Comment: This made it much easier and faster to save!

Comment: @sammytay10r note, unless you have some particular reason for needing a text file, you should probably use something like `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` instead of `numpy.savetxt` and `numpy.loadtxt`.